# How to properly pass server error response in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is a bit of a situation
after simple login

i'v tried to properly handle the server error response but at first i thought it will be simple. i was wrong.

the press login function rely on the login function to pass the login status to check if the user is or not logged.

in a way the code works but it will be great if can get the server response and display.

i've tried to use catch or get a response from the login function. either way still not getting the responde. please someone could spare a hint related to this of problem?

**login handler on login.jsx**

```
    pressLogin() {
        return auth
            .login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(response => {
                this.props.updateAuth();
                let res = response.text();

                if (response.login_status == false) {
                    let errors = res;
                    throw response.json();
                    //this.setState({ error: errors });
                } else {
                    // console.log('asdasd')
                    // this.forceUpdate();
                    this.setState({ redirectToHome: true });
                }
            })
            .catch(errors => {
                return errors;
                console.log("Error");
            });
    }
}
```

if i set a state in catch just setting a string works but it will be great if can get the server side errors

**the login on auth.js**

```
login(email, password) {
        return fetch("/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        })
            .then(resp => {
                if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
                    return resp.text();
                } else {
                    throw resp.json();
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.status) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("auth_token", response);
                    return {
                        login_status: true
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        login_status: false
                    };
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error" + error);
                return {
                    login_status: false
                };
            });
    },
```

Comment: A good way to have access to the response is to use redux and add your tokens in there. Then you can access them anywhere, in any component with this.props.auth_token.

Comment: @waz thank you, next time i'll try to learn redux